# PDFBox overview with class diagrams

Tags: java, uml

If I want to get an overview of the entire resource set of PDFBox, where is a good place to start? I want one partent diagram, and several smaller ones.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Do you think we should show relationships between classes in the java framework or classes in PDFBox-library?

Comment: The nest is to start hands on with the examples, not with some class graphics.